# How to rotate pseudo element css

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to recreate this icon using css pseudo elements (as a toggle indicator):

[image]

I have created the nececcary pseudo elements using `::after, ::before` and  tried to rotate them using `transform: rotate(90deg)`.

How can I tell them to rotate around their own center? I have tried `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` which does not work. Right now, both pseudo elements got the same `right: 10px;` but they are not placed above each other, instead they are next to each other.

You can check this [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/w46rgrss/1/) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform-origin` works fine, it's just that

a) 50% 50% (the object's center) is the default, and

b) you have to center the content of the box. That's a bit tricky because the icon you use doesn't require the full line height. Try adding

```
::before, ::after {
  padding-bottom: .17em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem without providing simply another solution, even if some of the others solution seem to be a better approach.

Answer (score 7):

First you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and create shape like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1072/)

[image]

After that you can rotate parent element for `45deg` and get desired result.

```css
.el {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
.el:before,
.el:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
.el:before {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
.el:after {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

**Update**: You can also add some transition on `:hover` like this

```css
.el {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.el:before,
.el:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.el:before {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
.el:after {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.el:hover:before {
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
.el:hover:after {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the style of #pseudo::after as `right: 0;`

```css
#div {
  background: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* tested but not working */
#pseudo::after,
#pseudo::before {
  /* transform-origin: 50% 50%; */
}


#pseudo::after {
  content: '›';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 40px;
}

#pseudo::before {
  content: '›';
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>

<div id="pseudo"></div>
```