# How to make this css-border around this shape?

Tags: html, css, border

**I Used to CSS-border-width to Make that shape but now I can't get a border around this shape.** Or there is another option to make this shape.

[image]

**Check Out On snippet**

```css
.month {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 61px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #008fc1;
  position: relative;
  top: -61px;
}

.month:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -61px;
  top: 61px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 61px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #acd3f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="month">
  <a href="#" class=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add the effect of a border using the other pseudo element: `.month::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 16px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #acd3f1;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate pseudo element css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613228/how-to-rotate-pseudo-element-css)

Comment: And btw, with the above suggestion, and as you use the same color on the bottom triangle and border, you can drop the existing `.month:after {}` rule (replace it with my properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below:

```css
.month {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,#008fc1 50%,#acd3f1  0) content-box,
  #acd3f1;
 padding:4px; /* to control the border */
 margin:25px;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="month">
</div>
```

You can easily do this with a pseudo element to be able to add content:

```css
.month {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:0;
 margin:25px;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:80px;
}

.month:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,#008fc1 50%,#acd3f1  0) content-box,
  #acd3f1;
 padding:4px; /* to control the border */
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="month">
  some text here
</div>
```